# The Functions resulting from Proof of Division Algorithm

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Proposition: For any $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \neq 0$, there
>   are unique $q, r \in \mathbb{N}$ such that \begin{align*}m = q · n + r
>  \quad\text{and}\quad r < n.\end{align*}

$\mathbb{N}$ denotes the set of natural numbers.

This proposition can be proven by induction hypothesis, which was straightforward to me. But the next part of my lecture notes confused me.

It stated that by this proposition, there are functions
$\operatorname{div} : \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\} \to \mathbb{N}$ and $\mod: \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\} \to N$,
where they give unique quotient and remainder respectively.

I sort of get how there would be two functions involving the relation of two sets of $\{m, n\}$ and {quotient}, {remainder}. But why is the domain part of the function noted as $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\}$?

Comment: "...such that $n\ne0$..."

Comment: omgg thx a lot!

Comment: $\mathbb N$ is not a clearly defined set. Some people think $0 \in \mathbb N$ and some think  $0 \not \in \mathbb N$. It's clear that you meant  $0 \in \mathbb N$ when you said $r<n$; but you shouldn't assume that everyone knows which definition you meant.